# why does this linq code get exponentially slower when applying First() to projection?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, profiling

I am trying to parse a 500K text file.

This is more of a learning exercise - I know there are other ways to get my result.

I may use the linq-go incorrectly, as I'm a bit new to it still.

My PC is fast.

I'm sure i'm making one of the "classic errors" here - so my QUESTION IS: which one is it and can I correct my logic or is this a bad fit for Linq all together?

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\aanodide\Desktop\APIUserGuide.txt");
    // add line numbers
    var qa = lines
        .Select((c,i) => new
        {
            i = i,
            c = c
        }); 
    var qb = qa.Skip(2312); // defs start at > 2312
    var qc = qb.Where( c => Regex.IsMatch(c.c, @"(\w+): ([a-zA-Z])?(.*)") );
    var qd = qc.Where( c => c.c.StartsWith("API Name:") );
    var qd_desc = qc.Where( c => c.c.StartsWith("Description:") ).Select( d => d.i );
     var qe = qd.Select( c => new {
        i = c.i,
        c = c.c,
        d = qd_desc.First(e => e > c.i) // --> IF I COMMENT OUT THIS, IT RUNS FAST, IN A FRACTION OF A SECOND<--
    }); 
     // Take(1) -> .013s
     // Take(10) -> .070s
     // Take(20) -> .446s
     // Take(40) -> 1.63s
     // Take(80) -> 6.49s
    foreach (var element in qe.Take(50))
    {
        Console.WriteLine (element.i);
    }
```

Comment: If I could teach everyone just *one thing* about LINQ it is this: the value of a query is **a query**. Not the values of the results of the query! The value of a query is *the query itself*. It doesn't give you results until you run the query, and *every* time you run the query, *the query runs*. If you don't want the query to run multiple times *then don't run the query multiple times*.

Comment: is there anything for linq that lets you diagram the execution path? my intuition is that a tool like that would have helped me solve this problem on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark noted, the whole query is iterated when you call `First()`. And `First()` is called once for every item in `qd` - meaning the whole file is parsed once for every item in `qd`.

To fix it, you can `ToList()` `qd_desc`, and do the `First()` on that list. Then it will only be evaluated once.

i.e.

```
var qd_desc = qc.Where( c => c.c.StartsWith("Description:") ).Select( d => d.i ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole query is executed (i.e., the sequence is iterated) when you call `First()`. When you call `Skip()`,`Where()`,`Select()`, or any operator that returns an `IEnumerable`, the query won't execute until you iterate over the sequence. The reason it happens on `First()` (or any operator that returns a single item) is that you're demanding a specific item right then and so the query *has* to be run to produce that result.

Comment: If all I do is comment out that line with first, the iteration of the sequence completes in a fraction of a second...

Comment: As @saus points out, you're calling `First()` for each item in `qd`.